# How can I perform delayed GUI changes while being able to see the before and after?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I need my GUI to feedback the user. For this purpose I color the background of a certain button in Green or Red according to the result of a certain verification. My purpose is to leave the Green color for several seconds and then return to the initial state (clear the fields and recover the button's original color).

My problem is that the "after" function, that I use for delaying the GUI before I return to the default GUI, doesn't show the before and after. I only see that the button is SUNKEN and then raised after the fields and buttons already returned to their defaults.

What am I doing wrong ?

```
if condition1 == condition2:
     orig_color = self.button2.cget("background")
     self.button2.config(bg='springgreen2')
     self.return2default(orig_color)
     self.after(3000) # 3 seconds delay to realize a Pass result
     # return to the defaults
     self.SN_field.delete("1.0", "end")
     self.HwVer_field.delete("1.0", "end")
     self.button2.config(bg=color)
else:
     self.button2.config(bg='red2')
```

Comment: `after(3000)` is the same as `time.sleep(3)` - it freezes your GUI, preventing it from being able to update. Have you searched this site for solutions? This sort of question has been asked and answered many times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want something to happen after a delay, move that "something" into a function and schedule it to be called with `after`. That will allow the event loop to continue to process events (including events that cause the display to refresh).

For example:

```
def reset(self):
    self.SN_field.dellete("1.0", ,"end")
    self.HwVer_field.delete("1.0", "end")
    self.button2.config(bg=color)
```

To call it, use `after`:

```
if condition1 == condition2:
    orig_color = self.button2.cget("background")
    self.button2.config(bg='springgreen2')
    self.return2default(orig_color)
    self.after(3000, self.reset)
```

When you call `after` with only a time argument, it causes your entire program to go to sleep, which means it is not able to update the display while it is sleeping.